# How to pass Yes to prompt by ionic platform command

Tags: bash, shell, ionic-framework, non-interactive

I have the below command in my shell script.

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

which prompts me to input 'Y' as below:

```
? Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n)
```

I wish to make this non-interactive thus i try to pass `Yes` using the below:

```
echo Y | ionic cordova platform add browser

Yes | ionic cordova platform add browser

ionic cordova platform add browser << 'Y'
```

With the above; the command executes non-interactive but accepts `No` instead of `Yes` as can be seen below:

```
[WARN] About to add the browser platform to your app.

       The browser Cordova platform is not recommended for production use.

       Instead, we recommend using platform detection and browser APIs to target web/PWA. See the Cross Platform docs[1]
       for details.

       Alternatively, ⚡️ Capacitor ⚡️ (https://ion.link/capacitor), Ionic's official native runtime, fully supports
       traditional web and Progressive Web Apps. See the Capacitor docs[2] to learn how easy it is to migrate.

       [1]: https://ion.link/cross-platform-docs
       [2]: https://ion.link/capacitor-cordova-migration-docs

--no-confirm: Are you sure you want to continue? No
```

Can you please suggest how to auto-enter `Yes` and make the command non-interactive ?

Comment: `--confirm`: Turn on auto-confirmation of confirmation prompts, and `--no-interactive`: Turn off interactive prompts and fancy outputs. The `--confirm` should auto-accept the prompt

Comment: @saperlipopette does not work !! i tried `ionic cordova platform add browser --confirm`

Comment: @saperlipopette This works -> `ionic cordova platform add browser --confirm --no-interactive`. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--confirm`: Turn on auto-confirmation of confirmation prompts
`--no-interactive`: Turn off interactive prompts and fancy outputs.

The `--confirm` should auto-accept the prompt

As you pointed out in your comment, this should allow to confirm the prompt and have a non-interactive mode

```
ionic cordova platform add browser --confirm --no-interactive
```